# Attach list of files and email using secure connection

Tags: python, email, ssl

Can I use this function to reliably attach a list of excel files to an email and create a secure connection to transmit said email? My python programming is self taught and I put this function together with a lot of google searches. (This function works, I use it, but I would like to have someone with more experience look it through, if possible)

Where can I improve my code? (Am I using the correct modules?)

```
import datetime
import smtplib
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email import Encoders

sMDY = datetime.date.today().strftime('%m/%d/%y')
lpath = 'C:/Path/to/my/excel/files/'
flist = ['excelfile_1.xlsx', 'excelfile_2.xlsx']

def EMAIL_FILES(flist):
    uname = 'username'
    pword = 'password'

    emailfrom = 'sender@domain.com'
    emailto = [
        'recipient_1@domain.com',
        'recipient_2@domain.com',
        ]

    body = ["The information transmitted is ..."]
    subject = ('Subject with date %s' % sMDY)

    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = emailfrom
    msg['To'] = ', '.join(emailto)
    msg['Subject'] = subject

    msg.attach(MIMEText(''.join(body)))

    ### ATTACH FILES
    for item in flist:
        part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")

        part.set_payload(open(lpath + item, "rb").read())

        Encoders.encode_base64(part)

        part.add_header('Content-Disposition',
                        'attachment; filename="%s"' % item)
        msg.attach(part)


    ### SECURE CONNECTION
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.domain.com:25')
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(uname, pword)

    server.sendmail(emailfrom, emailto, msg.as_string())
    server.quit()
```

Answer (score 4):

In general, the code looks good.  I just have a few miscellaneous remarks.

### Code organization

- Function names should be named `lower_case_with_underscores` by [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables).
- I would split the message composition and sending into separate functions.
- It is good practice to avoid embedding passwords into your source code.  I suggest storing the account information in a [YAML](http://pyyaml.org) file, or at least as constants in a separate Python module.
- The parameters are hard-coded, so the function is of limited utility.  The function could accept parameters with defaults:

  ```
  def compose_email(from='sender@example.com',
                    to=['recipient_1@example.com','recipient_2@example.com'],
                    attachments=[])
      …

  def send_email(msg, username, password)
      …
  ```

### Mail content

- The MIME type for .xlsx files is [`application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`](//stackoverflow.com/a/4212908/1157100).
- Concatenating file paths using [`os.path.join(lpath, item)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) would let you not have to worry about the path component separator.  Personally, I would choose to pass full paths to the function instead, to avoid assuming that they are all in some hard-coded directory:

  ```
  def EMAIL_FILES(attachments):
      …
      for path in attachments:
          with open(path, 'rb') as f:
              part = MIMEBase('application', 'vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
              part.set_payload(f.read())
              part.add_header('Content-Disposition',
                  'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(path))
              Encoders.encode_base64(part)
              msg.attach(part)
      …

  EMAIL_FILES([os.path.join('C:/Path/to/my/excel/files/', f) for f in
      ['excelfile_1.xlsx', 'excelfile_2.xlsx']
  ])
  ```
- I'm puzzled by why you defined `body` as a list of strings, only to join them all into one long string.  If the body contains non-trivial content, consider writing it as a ["""longstring"""](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-longstringitem).  Also, you may need to encode the `MIMEText` using [`Encoders.encode_quopri()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.encoders.html#email.encoders.encode_quopri).